# pytesseract - Read text from images with more accuracy

Tags: opencv, python-tesseract

I am working on `pytesseract`. I want to read data from Driving License kind of thing. Presently i am converting `.jpg` image to binary(gray scale) format using `opencv` but i am not accurate result. How do you solve this? Is there any standard size of image?

Answer (score 0):

Localize your detection by setting the rectangles where Tesseract has to look. You can then restrict according to rectangle which type of data is present at that place example: numerical,alphabets etc.You can also make a dictionary file for tesseract to improve accuracy(This can be used for detecting card holder name by listing common names in a file).  If there is disturbance in the background then design a filter to remove it. Good Luck!